# Error after login /etc/profile:line 38:8.0_121 Command Not Found

Tags: playonlinux

```
Error Found When Loading /etc/profile 
/etc/profile:line 38:8.0_121 Command Not Found
/etc/profile:line 45:20.0_121 Command Not Found
As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have modified `/etc/profile`. In particular, line `38` begins with `0.0_121` and line `45` begins with `20.0_121`.

Fix (or delete) these two lines.

Comment: Yes some  modification but i dont find line 38 begins with 0.0_121 and line 45 begins with 20.0_121.

Comment: Please [edit] (https://askubuntu.com/posts/908724/edit) your post, and cut and paste the result of `cat -n /etc/profile | head -n 50`, then, select the whole region, and format it with `{}`